# How to share or pass variables between multiple classes in Locust?

Tags: python, locust

I am trying to write a simple performance test task using Locust. I have two sequential HTTP tasks, and if I set the variables in one class it works fine. However I want to split the tasks into two classes as shown below. I need to use the variable from the first class in another class.

How can I achieve that?

```py
# FIRST CLASS
from locust import SequentialTaskSet

class MySeqTask1(SequentialTaskSet):

    @task
    def get_status1(self):
        r = self.client.get("/200")
        print("1. Status of 200")
        self.data = 20 # ***VARIABLE TO BE SHARED TO SECOND CLASS***
```

```py
#SECOND CLASS 
from locust import SequentialTaskSet, HttpUser, constant, task,FastHttpUser
from sampleLocust import MySeqTask1
    
class MySeqTask2(SequentialTaskSet):

    @task
    def get_status3(self):
        obj = MySeqTask1(self)
        self.client.get(f"/301")
        print("3. Status of 301")
        print(obj.data) # ***USING VARIABLE FROM FIRST CLASS***

    class MyLoadTest(FastHttpUser):
       host = "https://http.cat"
       tasks = [MySeqTask1,MySeqTask2]
       wait_time = constant(1)
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Command to run the program : locust -f utils/Baseclassone.py --headless -u 1 -r 1 -t 1m

print(obj.data) # ***USING VARIABLE FROM FIRST CLASS***
AttributeError: 'MySeqTask1' object has no attribute 'data'
```

Comment: do you get error or what? We can't run it and we can't read in your mind. You have to show all details in question (not in comments)

Comment: maybe keep it as global variable outside classes. OR you may have to first set default value for `self.data` in first class using `__init__`

Comment: problem can be system creates own instance of `MySeqTaks1` and it keep data in own instance - and you can't access it. Creating `MySeqTask1(self)` in `get_status3()` can gives access to original instance created by system. You have to keep it this data outside classes.

Comment: @furas Please find the error message as well

Comment: as I said - you can't access it. System creates instance of `MySeqTaks1()` which creates `self.data` but you can't get access this instance. And creating new instance in `MySeqTask2` is useless - it is totally different object which doesn't have `self.data`. You have to keep it as global variable outside classes.

Comment: eventually you may check class `FastHttpUser` if you can create own method which create instances and it could create instance `MySeqTask1` and send it as parameter to `MySeqTask2`.

Comment: but I see other problem - it may run `MySeqTask1` and `MySeqTask2` in different order and `MySeqTask1 will not have `self.data` when `MySeqTask2` will need to access it. you should keep functions in one class `SequentialTaskSet`

Comment: @furas thanks for you comments, however is there any way which we can use variable from once class in another class using python. I think this can resolve the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set your variables on the User instead of on the TaskSet. It is accessible as self.user in the TaskSet, e.g.

```
self.user.data = 20
```

Comment: could you please elaborate or give me an example. What is mean by User .